# Condition for positive semidefiniteness for this special block matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, semidefinite-programming, positive-semidefinite

Consider a finite matrix with the following structure

$$
        \left(
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
        1 & \vec{u} & \vec{u} & \vec{u} &...\\
        \vec{u}^T & X & P & P & ...\\
        \vec{u}^T & P^T & Y & P & ... \\
        \vec{u}^T & P^T & P^T & Z & ... \\
        ... & ... & ... & ... & ...
    \end{array}
    \right)
$$

where, *e.g.*, $\vec{u}=(a, b)$, with $a, b$ real constants, $P$ is a $2 \times 2$ real matrix (eventually such that $P=P^T$), $X = \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & x \\ x & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, with $x$ real unknown, and similarly for $Y$, $Z$, ...

Knowing $\vec{u}$ and $P$, I would like to know if there exist some $x,y,z,...$, such that the matrix is positive semidefinite.

Do you know if there is a way of doing this without running a SDP on the full matrix, but for example only on some minors? Or, is it possible to decompose it in a block-diagonal structure, and run the SDP on the blocks?

Thank you for your help.